# Conditional Formatting in Access with Disabled or 'Read-only' Textboxes

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have an Access Continuous Form with some bound textboxes. I want to provide a visual indicator of the status of each record, so the textbox contains a value, either 0, 1 or 2 from the table. The conditional format turns this box either Green for 0, Yellow for 1, and Red for 2 including the text colour so the box is literally just a colour for the user.

I have disabled the textbox to prevent the user being able to click into the box and seeing that it is a textbox, but setting `Enabled = False` to the properties seems to turn off with conditional formatting. I have then applied the `Enabled` box in the Conditional Formatting but whilst that does disable the textbox, it turns off the conditional formatting, and if you lock it, it won't change the text colour.

Is there another control I'd be better off using here, or is there away to allow the textbox conditional format to work without the user being able to click into the textbox?

Comment: What about property `Locked`?

Comment: Thanks @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns - I did mention that unfortunately, doing this does keep the `BackColor` property intact, but unfortunately changes the `ForeColor` to a default Grey/Black.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To disable clicking into the textbox, it must have

```
Enabled = False
Locked = True
```

To not overwrite this with Conditional Formatting, the format condition must include `Enabled = False` as well.

Note that in the Conditional Formatting dialog, it will look as if the color doesn't work - the dialog doesn't know about `Locked = True`. But it will work in the form.

I remember having problems setting `Enabled = False` in the dialog (this was in Access 2010), so I used code to create it:

```vb
' myForm must be open in Design view
Public Sub MyCreateCondFormat()

    Dim F As Form_myForm
    Dim fld As TextBox
    Dim objFrc As FormatCondition

    Set F = Form_myForm

    Set fld = F.myTextbox
    fld.FormatConditions.Delete

    Set objFrc = fld.FormatConditions.Add(acFieldValue, acEqual, "42")
    With objFrc
        .Enabled = False    ' <----------
        .ForeColor = &H0000FF
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Andre: this is great! I did not know that FormatConditions.Add is possible.

Comment: Thanks so much @Andre - this worked perfectly. The UI is very misleading and for future readers, as Andre alluded to above, the preview box shows a completely different output, but it does work as intended in the Form. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Enabled = False changes the color of background. If you set Locked = False it just prevents the user to change the data. 
Your check box has to have

```
Enabled = True
Locked = True
```

I tested it with this condition and it works:

[image: Conditional formatting]
[image: Results]

Comment: But even if you can't change the value, you can click into the textbox, which may be undesirable.

Comment: Set focus to a different control in On_Enter event.